# Excel VBA: path to folder with unknown foldername but known extension

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I have this `Excel` file that I use to modify and export datasets. It exports to the same folder, located in:

```
C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\xxxxxx.cv\Addresses.xlsm
```

I'd like to store this `.xlsm` in:

```
C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\
```

instead, but I still need to export to the

```
C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\xxxxxx.cv\
```

folder. However this is tricky as the `xxxxxx.cv` foldername changes project to project, however the `.cv` extension of this foldername is always the same.

Currently it uses following to make export files to root folder of the excel file:

```
convFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\conv" & convTableNumber
```

I'd like it to work essensially like this, obviously this doesn't work, but how would I achieve this functionality?

```
 convFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & \*.cv & "\conv" & convTableNumber
```

Edit. Solution:

```
Dim sFile As String, sPathSeek As String, sPathMatch As String
On Error Resume Next
sPathSeek = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.cv"
sFile = Dir(sPathSeek, vbDirectory)

Do While Len(sFile) > 0
    If Left(sFile, 1) <> "." Then
        If (GetAttr(sFile) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            sPathMatch = sFile
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
    sFile = Dir
Loop

convFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sPathMatch & "\conv" & convTableNumber
```

Comment: So there is always one and only one folder in `C:\BASE` that's name is ended with `.cv`?

Comment: Yes in C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\ there is always just one folder with name ending in .cv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by this statement

> Yes in C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\ there is always just one folder with name ending in .cv

I borrowed this code form [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/650268-excel-vba-get-full-folder-name-folder-path-wildcard.html) and tweaked it a little

```
Sub Find_SubFolder()
    Dim sFile As String, sPathSeek As String, sPathMatch As String

    Const sMainPath As String = "C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\"

    On Error Resume Next
    sPathSeek = sMainPath & "*.cv"
    sFile = Dir(sPathSeek, vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        If Left(sFile, 1) <> "." Then
            If (GetAttr(sFile) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                sPathMatch = sFile
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        sFile = Dir
    Loop

    'From here you can put your code to save your file...
    Debug.print "C:\BASE\yyyyyy.c8\" & sPathMatch & "\"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to read a directory to look for a specific suffix and return what the name is:

```
Function FindFileNameBySuffix(InDir As String, suffix As String)


    Dim foundFileName     As String
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(InDir)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)

    For Each oFile In oFiles
        If Right(oFile.Name, Len(suffix)) = suffix Then
            FindFileNameBySuffix = oFile.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next


End Function
```